# Eclipse export to runnable .jar

Tags: java, eclipse

I click on a file, choose -> export -> runnable JAR file. The problem is that some of the projects (and classes) do not appear in "Launch configuration" even that they contain a main class, which means I can't export them. What should I do ?

Comment: Thanks, running the project solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the project as Java Application. It'll create that configuration automatically. Alternatively, you can go to [`run configurations`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm) and create a configuration yourself manually.